# How to use certificate in https Apache server with client Java

Tags: java, apache, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using an Apache server to provide a https access to some files in this server. The client use Java program to access these files via a proxy.

In my apache configuration:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
```

The structure of the file `apache.pem`:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The client code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URL website = new URL("https://mywebsite.com/file.zip");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching website.com found
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1697)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:257)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:251)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1165)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:945)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1217)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1201)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1031)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:38)
```

What I need to do to get Java understand my certificate? Do I need to regenerate the certificate with apache tool or java keytool? Thanks

Comment: is this a self-signed certificate? If so, you'll need to provide the CA (own created one) in the form of a keystore

Comment: You may get solution in following link

[Apache HttpClient get server certificate][1]

[Using Apache httpclient for https][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13274316/1081776
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5232489/1081776